# character encoding when transforming special characters in JSON into CSV (excel)

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

I am currently trying to populate a .csv file from a json using

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
```

i've read the default encoding they use is utf-8, some of my JSON has special characters, emoji, or chinese letters in it.. here's an example

```
[ { username: 'jung.y00n',
    name: '정 윤',
    bio:
     'ғʀᴇᴇʟᴀɴᴄᴇʀᴍᴏᴅᴇʟ\nᴄᴏɴᴛᴀᴄᴛ  ᴅᴍ 사적/공구 연락 확인 못해요\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\n바이오리 슬림/브이 스틱 (10/14-16)',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsjung.y00n.jpg' } ]

[ { username: 'yujing.lai',
    name: '勇闖美利堅的美少女 * Miss.Amber',
    bio:
     'San Francisco,California USA\nAcademy of Art UniversityMaster of Fine Arts\nNational Taiwan University of ArtBFA\n✈️',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsyujing.lai.jpg' } ]

[ { username: 'rky_thitiworada',
    name: 'ฐิติวรดา จังจริง',
    bio:
     'Thitiworada Janjring\nDJ.Rky\nI\'m interested in music,mixing,EDM,DJ   \n ติดต่องาน ☎️ 097-0922200 \nติดต่องาน ID line➡️  djrky  \n#msrk  @mashiimx',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsrky_thitiworada.jpg' } ]

[ { username: 'mimisayhihi',
    name: '米恩綺Mimi',
    bio:
     'Taipei \n工作聯繫窗口\nKaren ：karen@cclfilm.com \n方慈/judy@ cclfilm.com \n活動邀約/hihifish1128@gmail.com',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsmimisayhihi.jpg' } ]
```

however after exporting the JSON to csv and open it in ms excel in windows it looked like this

[image]

Any idea on what i need to do to make this encoded and shown correctly ?

Comment: guess you need to write to a xlsx file with the correct encoding .not for csv file

Comment: You should add the UTF-8 BOM at the start of the text, like:
var csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W432s/)

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to the file to tell Excel to decode the characters correctly, this should do the trick:

```
const users = [ { username: 'jung.y00n',
    name: '정 윤',
    bio:
    'ғʀᴇᴇʟᴀɴᴄᴇʀᴍᴏᴅᴇʟ\nᴄᴏɴᴛᴀᴄᴛ  ᴅᴍ 사적/공구 연락 확인 못해요\n⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀\n바이오리 슬림/브이 스틱 (10/14-16)',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsjung.y00n.jpg' } 
,
{ username: 'yujing.lai',
    name: '勇闖美利堅的美少女 * Miss.Amber',
    bio:
    'San Francisco,California USA\nAcademy of Art UniversityMaster of Fine Arts\nNational Taiwan University of ArtBFA\n✈️',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsyujing.lai.jpg' } 
,
{ username: 'rky_thitiworada',
    name: 'ฐิติวรดา จังจริง',
    bio: 'Thitiworada Janjring\nDJ.Rky\nI\'m interested in music,mixing,EDM,DJ   \n ติดต่องาน ☎️ 097-0922200 \nติดต่องาน ID line➡️  djrky  \n#msrk  @mashiimx',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsrky_thitiworada.jpg' } 
,
{ username: 'mimisayhihi',
    name: '米恩綺Mimi',
    bio:
    'Taipei \n工作聯繫窗口\nKaren ：karen@cclfilm.com \n方慈/judy@ cclfilm.com \n活動邀約/hihifish1128@gmail.com',
    pic_url: 'C:/Users/Administrator/Downloadsmimisayhihi.jpg' } 
];

const fs = require("fs");
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

const outputFile = "users.csv";
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: outputFile,
    header: Object.keys(users[0]).map(key => { return {id: key, title: key} })
});

function prependBOM(file) {
    let fileContents = fs.readFileSync(file);
    fs.writeFileSync(file, "\ufeff" + fileContents);
}

async function writeCSV() {
    await csvWriter.writeRecords(users);
    // Prepend BOM to file so Excel will display characters correctly.
    prependBOM(outputFile);    
}

writeCSV();
```

If you *don't* want to do this, you can import UTF-8 data manually into Excel:

- Start Excel.
- Import your csv data using Data->Import External Data->Import Data
- Select file type "csv", browse to your file and select it.
- In the import wizard change the File_Origin to "65001 (UTF-8)".
- You can then click "Transform data" to see your data.
- You can select close and load to create a new worksheet with your imported data.

Comment: Yes, either way will tell Excel the character encoding of the text file. That's fundamental to any program reading and text file, which is one of many reasons that CSV is a weak format.